# How to index a dataframe column and store values of a query to another variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, a column in data frame called income has values '>50K' and '<=50K'. how to store values with >50k in a separate data frame/variable called incomegt ?

i have tried to query the dataframe and set the query condition as '>50K'
and many other things. none of them have worked.
is '>50K' in this case considered as string? or a number?

```
incomegt = dataset_class.query(income == '>50K')
incomegt = dataset_class[dataframe_class.income > dataframe_class.income]
incomegt = dataset_class.query(income > 50K)
```

expected result should be a variable/dataframe incomegt that has income values >50K

Comment: Is definitely a string. Try with [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html): `dataset_class.loc[dataset_class['income'] == '>50K']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` method must be passed a string.  Try:

```
incomegt = dataset_class.query("income=='>50K'")
```

You could also use a boolean index to slice the column.

```
incomegt = dataset_class.loc[dataset_class.income.eq('>50K')]
```

Comment: thank you very much. i had already tried the first one, it didnot work. it returned just the column labels. But the second statement worked.